# Render Esri Map in Sencha-Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, esri

I've got a problem to render an esri Map with sencha touch. I display a tabPanel with a tab containing the map, and 3 other tabs.

My problem is that when I'm on another tab than the map-tab, when I resize the window (or change orientation of phone), the map diseapears.

I identified the source of the problem. when I resize the window being on another tab, the map tab goes from current size to 0x0 to the new size. Problem is that when the width and height are set to 0x0, the Esri Map require tiles of dimension 0x0, and then the error appears.

I tried to set minWidth and minHeight to my tab but without success.

do you have any clue how i could fix that ??

thank you in advance !

Comment: Karudosu, I am planning to use sencha touch with Esri javascript API. Can you show me a sample on how to use the sencha touch with esri it would be really helpful. You could also send it to my email address at pkvenu@gmail.com . Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had the same problem (I didn't really know the exact cause at the time).  Whenever the orientation of the screen changed I was manually changing the dimensions of the esri map to match the panel and then firing the map's reposition and resize methods.  However, if this was fired from a different panel, the basemaps would drop out of the map.

I was able to fix this by calling the following function every time orientation changed, or the map panel was set as active:

```
function resizeMapDiv(){
    if (appPanel.getActiveItem() === mapPanel){
        var mapdiv = document.getElementById('mapDiv');
        var mappanel = document.getElementById('mapPanel');

        if ((mapdiv != null) && (mappanel != null) && (mapdiv.style.width != mappanel.style.width)){
            mapdiv.style.width = mappanel.style.width;
            mapdiv.style.height = mappanel.style.height;

            map.reposition();
            map.resize();
        }
    }
}
```